# EF Code First 1:0..1 relationship shared primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a relationship that I need to model that is 1:0..1. Class A has a required reference to Class B, but Class B can exist without Class A.

My understanding (which could be wrong) is that this EF can only create this relationship in such a way that Class A does not have its own Primary Key but uses the same Primary Key as Class B. Class A is the dependent entity, Class B is the primary.

Is it possible to edit an existing Class A (with a link to a specific Class B) and change it to link to a different Class B? What happens to its primary key? What happens to other entities that reference Class A?

Comment: You mean you now have *classes* A-B, which now should become A-C in the class model? Or two *objects* a-b1, which should become a-b2?

Comment: Person class has a reference to Address class. A Person must have an Address, but Address could be used for other classes such as Company. So, when I create a Person I also create an Address with it. The Address table holds the Primary Key, which is then assigned to the Person as well. What happens if the Person "moves"?  Historical data such as Deliveries are linked to the old Address, so I don't want to just edit that record, I need to keep the old Address in the system.

Comment: In that case I think Person-Address should be many-to-many, while the junction table has a field that indicates which address is current. You can't change the primary key of Person (I assume other entities refer to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class PrimaryEntity
{
    public PrimaryEntity()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class DependentEntity
{
    public DependentEntity()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid CurrentPrimaryEntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual PrimaryEntity CurrentPrimaryEntity { get; set; } 
}
    // override this in DataContext
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DependentEntity>().HasRequired(a => a.CurrentPrimaryEntity).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.CurrentPrimaryEntityId);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

 protected override void Seed(MyDataComtext db)
    {
        // here is a restriction that FK must be unique
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE dbo.[DependentEntity] ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Dependent UNIQUE(CurrentPrimaryEntityId)");

    }

var primary = new PrimaryEntity();
 db.PrimaryEntity.Add(PrimaryEntity);
var dependent = new DependentEntity();
dependent.CurrentPrimaryEntity = primary;  
  db.DependentEntity.Add(dependent);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

something like this

Comment: It's the "WithMany" that I always struggle to get my mind around. It's counter-intuitive because there's never more then one.  So, if I want to restrict further restrict it so that there's never more then one dependent linked to the same primary, then I guess that's on my business logic, not EF?

Comment: I guess it's that you need. Both entityes may have it's own PK. Primary Item is independent and even doesn't know about Dependent one.